# Not able to get the data from asp.net mvc controller to angularjs using ajax call

Tags: angularjs, ajax, asp.net-mvc

i am able to hit the controller method and able to return the data

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetAppsList()
    {          
        var Apps = DataModel.ApplicationMasters.ToList();
        return Json(new { appslist = Apps }); 
       // return AppsList;
    }
```

but in angular js not able to get the data

```
myApp.controller('SpicyController', ['$scope','$http', function ($scope,$http) {    
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'Home/GetAppsList'
}).then(function (response) {
$scope.appslist = response.data.appslist; }, function (error) {console.log(error);});}]);
```

in view

```
<div class="main" ng-app="spiceApp">
    <div ng-controller="SpicyController"> 
        <table>          
            <tr ng-repeat="app in appslist">
                <td>
                    {{app.Name}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
       </div>
    </div>
```

can you help me why i am not able to display result?

Comment: Check network traffic and look at what data is being returned from your controller. Should help you figure it out. If I had to guess (and I do), it's a casing issue.

Comment: i don't know how to check network traffic for my application, can you help me out?

Comment: in your browser, press F12. It'll open developer tools. On of the tabs will be network. If chrome, it's already running, just take a look. If IE, press the start button to start capturing. if another browser, you'll have a bit of research to do.

Comment: Thanks Mike i am getting below error

Comment: angular.js:7918 GET http://localhost:37481/Home/GetAppsList 500 (Internal Server Error)
(anonymous) @ angular.js:7918
C @ angular.js:7750
f @ angular.js:7484
C @ angular.js:10725
C @ angular.js:10725
(anonymous) @ angular.js:10811
$eval @ angular.js:11726
$digest @ angular.js:11554
$apply @ angular.js:11832
(anonymous) @ angular.js:1297
d @ angular.js:3678
c @ angular.js:1295
Xb @ angular.js:1309
Sc @ angular.js:1258
(anonymous) @ angular.js:20364
a @ angular.js:2336
(anonymous) @ angular.js:2604
q @ angular.js:300
c @ angular.js:2603

Comment: do you have any idea?

Comment: @GirishkumarGorantla as mentioned Mike please check Network tab error details. Instead of console tab, check network tab. if error not showing in network reload page you'll see the error.

Comment: 500 internal server error means a server-side error - probably your controller method or something else in the asp.net pipeline is crashing. If you debug the controller does it throw an exception? Also, as the others said, check the network tab and see if both the request and response data for your ajax call appear to be as you expected.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on 'var Apps = DataModel.ApplicationMasters.ToList();' and then see where it fails on debugging

Comment: Thanks All, error because of i am sending Json data it is serializable

Comment: and Application Master have circular reference thats why getting 500 error

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="main" ng-app="spiceApp">
<div ng-controller="SpicyController"> 
    <table>          
        <tr ng-repeat="(index,data) in appslist">
            <td>
                {{data.Name}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
   </div>
</div>
```

applist is an Object . To Apply ng-repeat on an Object write this `ng-repeat=(index,data) in applist`.

```
myApp.controller('SpicyController', ['$scope','$http', function ($scope,$http) {    
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    type:'json',
    url: 'Home/GetAppsList'
}).then(function (response) {
$scope.appslist = response.data.appslist; }, function (error) {console.log(error);});}]);
```